# Bar position between 2 x-axis value in time type bar chart

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I would like to vertically align the bars of my chart between each couple of values in the x-axis.

The current version of my bar chart is : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/29/3/1563363518-barchartscreenshot.png

What I would like to do is : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/29/3/1563363518-centeredbarsobjective.png

This is for an Angular 7 application with the following dependencies to use chart.js : "chart.js": "^2.8.0", "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.6.0", "ng2-charts": "^2.2.0"

Here is the configuration of my bar chart :

```
  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          barPercentage: 0.9,
          categoryPercentage: 1.0,
          stacked: true,
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            parser: 'HH',
            unit: 'hour',
            unitStepSize: 1,
            displayFormats: {
                hour: 'HH',
            }
          }
        },
      ],
      yAxes: [{
          stacked: true
        }
      ]
    },
    legend: { 
      position: 'bottom' 
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Data distribution',
      position: 'top'
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        display: true,
        align: 'center',
        anchor: 'center'
      }
    }
  };
  public barChartLabels: Label[] = ['12','13','14','15'];
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [pluginDataLabels];
  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [{
    data: [40, 80, 60], 
    label: 'Series A' 
  },
  {
    data: [10, 30, 50], 
    label: 'Series B'

  }];
```

[Stackblitz of the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-chartjs-barchart-verticalalign)

Thanks for your help :)

Lucas